# How do I get the multimedia keys on my keyboard to do anything?

Tags: keyboard, macos, keybindings

I have a Sierra mac with a MS Natural Key 4000 keyboard.  It's got a bunch of special keys that I'd like to do stuff with.  Out of the box, only volume up/down/mute and play/pause work do anything.

I tried using BeardedSpice to bind these keys.  It didn't respond when I hit them.  Karabiner-EventView wasn't any better - I could see other keys being typed, but these ones didn't trigger anything.

Comment: Grab [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) from the App Store & make sure they even generate a code. If not, you're out of luck.

Comment: @Tetsujin seriously?  No key code = no other options?  This OS is so different than linux...

Comment: Well, if it doesn't actually supply a key code, there's nothing to translate. media keys get intercepted before they reach the OS, so the OS needs to know what to do with them. Presumably as it's a non-Apple keyboard it doesn't have Mac drivers.

Comment: Makes sense.  I just figured *something* would come out of the keyboard that I could translate into a media key.  Feel free to promote your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!  USB overdrive heard the keys and let me map them to arbitrary osascript.  http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html

Comment: Glad you got it. I would have mentioned USB Overdrive, but I didn't realise it handled keyboards, I thought it was only mice.

Answer (score 0):

Media keys seem to be intercepted below the OS level - I'm not sure how so was waiting to see if anyone had a better answer...

If an app such as [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) cannot see the key-presses, then that makes it much harder to intercept & translate.

Potentially an app like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) might be able to do it, however it has problems with Sierra at the moment.

Comment: So here's a weird observation.  Mute and volume keys give me mute, volume_decrement, and volume_increment in Karabiner event viewer.  Play/pause shows nothing.  But it still toggles playback.